# How to solve this without using queues, stacks, or arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, stack, queue

Recently I had an interview and was given a following question. The trick is solving this problem without queues, stacks, or arrays. I wasn't able to answer this question. Needless to say, I didn't get the job. How would you solve this problem.

You are given a deck containing N cards.  While holding the deck:

1. Take the top card off the deck and set it on the table
2. Take the next card off the top and put it on the bottom of the deck
   in your hand.
3. Continue steps 1 and 2 until all cards are on the table.  This is a
   round.
4. Pick up the deck from the table and repeat steps 1-3 until the deck
   is in the original order.

Write a program to determine how many rounds it will take to put a
deck back into the original order.  This will involve creating a data
structure to represent the order of the cards. Do not use an array.
This program should be written in C only. It should take a number of
cards in the deck as a command line argument and write the result to
stdout.  Please ensure the program compiles and runs correctly (no
pseudo-code).  This isn't a trick question; it should be fairly
straightforward.

Comment: Do you even need a data structure for that? Hm... And why would anyone ask such a question which is most likely devoid of any relevance for any kind of job?

Comment: In the first line is *"The trick is..."* but in the last line is *"This isn't a trick question"*. Or perhaps *"trick*" was meant to be ambiguous since it involves a deck of cards. Be happy you didn't get the job.

Comment: I'm not sure, what precisely they meant by no queues, but I don't see the word "list" in the list of excluded words. Maybe that was the "trick". Anyway, for a 32 card deck, there are less than `2^(5*32) = 2^160` possible permutations of the cards, so you might also have gotten away with using three `unsigned long long`s + bit fiddling. But I think, I would have gone for the list.

Comment: @ryyker this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see  [Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: People down vote all sorts of questions these days. I also fail to see a pattern. If someone accesses arrays out of bounds it gets down voted. If someone asks about an algorithm it gets down voted...If someone is a fan boy of technology xy and the question is a bit on the critical side it gets down voted...

Comment: @gnat - My bad.  Comment removed.

Comment: The answer is the least-common-multiple of the lengths of the rotation groups. For example, given N=11 the lengths of the rotation groups are 5,3,3 so it takes 15 rounds to put the deck back into order. The question is, "How do you find the lengths of the rotation groups?"

Comment: @user3386109 I tried looking up what a rotation group is and wikipedia gave me something related to dynamics, [Rotation group SO(3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)). I like math enthusiast (always was interested in it, but not smart enough to actually discover anything). I would really appreciate if you could elaborate more on this topic. Or maybe give me some pointers where I can find more information about this.

Comment: @flashburn I added an answer, since it was too long to fit in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any obvious way to find out the lengths of the cyclic groups [user3386109 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29427293/1475978), **without** using any arrays.

Besides, the *"This is not a trick [interview] question"* sounds to me like the interviewer just wanted you to simulate the deck operations in C using something other than an array.

The immediate solution that comes to mind is using singly or doubly linked lists. Personally, I'd use a singly-linked list for the cards, and a deck structure to hold the pointers for the first and last cards in the deck, as the shuffling operation moves cards to both top and bottom of decks:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct card {
    struct card *next;
    long         face; /* Or index in the original order */
};

typedef struct deck {
    struct card *top;
    struct card *bottom;
} deck;

#define EMPTY_DECK { NULL, NULL }
```

The deck manipulation functions I'd use would be

```
static void add_top_card(deck *const d, struct card *const c)
{
    if (d->top == NULL) {
        c->next = NULL;
        d->top = c;
        d->bottom = c;
    } else {
        c->next = d->top;
        d->top = c;
    }
}

static void add_bottom_card(deck *const d, struct card *const c)
{
    c->next = NULL;
    if (d->top == NULL)
        d->top = c;
    else
        d->bottom->next = c;
    d->bottom = c;
}

static struct card *get_top_card(deck *const d)
{
    struct card *const c = d->top;
    if (c != NULL) {
        d->top = c->next;
        if (d->top == NULL)
            d->bottom = NULL;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Since there is no `get_bottom_card()` function, there is no need to use a doubly-linked list to describe the cards.

The shuffling operation itself is quite simple:

```
static void shuffle_deck(deck *const d)
{
    deck hand  = *d;
    deck table = EMPTY_DECK;
    struct card *topmost;

    while (1) {

        topmost = get_top_card(&hand);
        if (topmost == NULL)
            break;

        /* Move topmost card from hand deck to top of table deck. */
        add_top_card(&table, topmost);

        topmost = get_top_card(&hand);
        if (topmost == NULL)
            break;

        /* Move topmost card from hand deck to bottom of hand deck. */
        add_bottom_card(&hand, topmost);
    }

    /* Pick up the table deck. */
    *d = table;
}
```

The benefit of the `deck` structure type with pointers to both ends of the card list, is avoiding the linear search in `shuffle_deck()` to find the last card in the hand deck (for fast appending to the hand deck). Some quick tests I did indicates that linear search would otherwise have been the bottleneck, increasing runtime by about half.

Some results:

```
Cards   Rounds
   2        2
   3        3
   4        2
   5        5
   6        6
   7        5
   8        4
   9        6
  10        6
  11       15
  12       12
  13       12
  14       30
  15       15
  16        4
  20       20
  30       12
  31      210
  32       12
  50       50
  51       42
  52      510  (one standard deck)
  53       53
  54     1680
  55      120
  56     1584
  57       57
  80      210
  81     9690
  82    55440
  83     3465
  84     1122
  85     5040
  99      780
 100      120
 101     3360
 102       90
 103     9690
 104     1722  (two decks)
 156     5040  (three decks)
 208  4129650  (four decks)
```

---

However, **using arrays**, one can easily find out the cycle lengths, and use those to compute the number of rounds needed.

First, we create a graph or mapping how the card positions change during a full round:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

size_t *mapping(const size_t cards)
{
    size_t *deck, n;

    if (cards < (size_t)1) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    deck = malloc(cards * sizeof *deck);
    if (deck == NULL) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    for (n = 0; n < cards; n++)
        deck[n] = n;

    n = cards;

    while (n > 2) {
        const size_t c0 = deck[0];
        const size_t c1 = deck[1];
        memmove(deck, deck + 2, (n - 2) * sizeof *deck);
        deck[n-1] = c0;
        deck[n-2] = c1;
        n--;
    }
    if (n == 2) {
        const size_t c = deck[0];
        deck[0] = deck[1];
        deck[1] = c;
    }

    return deck;
}
```

The above function returns an array of indexes, corresponding to where the card ends up after each full round. Because these indexes indicate *card position*, every round performs the exact same operation.

The function is not optimized or even terribly efficient; it uses `memmove()` to keep the top of the deck at the start of the array. Instead, one could treat the initial part of the array as a cyclic buffer.

If you have difficulty comparing the function to the original instructions, the intent is to always take two topmost cards, and move the first to the top of the result deck, and the second to the bottom of the hand deck. If there are just two cards left, the first card goes to the result deck first, the second card last. If there is only one card left, it obviously goes to the result deck. In the function, the first `n` entries in the array are the hand deck, and the last `cards-n` entries are the table deck.

To find out the number of cycles, we simply need to traverse each cycle in the above graph or mapping:

```
size_t *cycle_lengths(size_t *graph, const size_t nodes)
{
    size_t *len, i;

    if (graph == NULL || nodes < 1) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    len = malloc(nodes * sizeof *len);
    if (len == NULL) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
        size_t c = i;
        size_t n = 1;

        while (graph[c] != i) {
            c = graph[c];
            n++;
        }

        len[i] = n;
    }

    return len;
}
```

This function too could be enhanced quite a bit. This one traverses every cycle the number of positions in that cycle times, instead of just traversing each cycle only once, and assigning the cycle length to all participants in the cycle.

For the next steps, we need to know all primes up to and including the number of cards. (Including, because we might have only one cycle, so the largest length we might see is the number of cards in the deck.) One simple option is to use a bit map and [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

```
#ifndef ULONG_BITS
#define ULONG_BITS (sizeof (unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT)
#endif

unsigned long *sieve(const size_t limit)
{
    const size_t   bytes = (limit / ULONG_BITS + 1) * sizeof (unsigned long);
    unsigned long *prime;
    size_t         base;

    prime = malloc(bytes);
    if (prime == NULL) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }
    memset(prime, ~0U, bytes);

    /* 0 and 1 are not considered prime. */
    prime[0] &= ~(3UL);

    for (base = 2; base < limit; base++) {
        size_t i = base + base;
        while (i < limit) {
            prime[i / ULONG_BITS] &= ~(1UL << (i % ULONG_BITS));
            i += base;
        }
    }

    return prime;
}
```

Since it is possible that there is only one cycle, covering all cards, you will want to supply *the number of cards* + 1 to the above function.

Let's see how the above would work. Let's define some array variables we need:

```
size_t         cards;  /* Number of cards in the deck */
unsigned long *prime;  /* Bitmap of primes */
size_t        *graph;  /* Card position mapping */
size_t        *length; /* Position cycle lengths, for each position */
size_t        *power;
```

The last one, 'power', should be allocated and initialized to all zeros. We will be using only entries [2] to [cards], inclusive. The intent is to be able to calculate the result as ∏(p^power[p]), p=2..cards.

Start by generating the mapping, and calculating the cycle lengths:

```
graph = mapping(cards);
length = cycle_lengths(graph, cards);
```

To calculate the number of rounds, we need to factorize the cycle lengths, and calculate the product of the highest power of each factor in the lengths. (I'm not a mathematician, so if someone can explain this correctly/better, any and all help is appreciated.)

Perhaps actual code describes it better:

```
size_t p, i;
prime = sieve(cards + 1);
for (p = 2; p <= cards; p++)
    if (prime[p / ULONG_BITS] & (1UL << (p % ULONG_BITS))) {
        /* p is prime. */
        for (i = 0; i < cards; i++)
            if (length[i] > 1) {
                size_t n = 0;

                /* Divide out prime p from this length */
                while (length[i] % p == 0) {
                    length[i] /= p;
                    n++;
                }

                /* Update highest power of prime p */
                if (power[p] < n)
                    power[p] = n;
            }
    }
```

and the result, using floating-point math in case `size_t` is not large enough,

```
double result = 1.0;
for (p = 2; p <= cards; p++) {
    size_t n = power[p];
    while (n-->0)
        result *= (double)p;
}
```

I have verified that the two solutions produce exact same results for decks of up to 294 cards (the slow non-array solution just took too long for 295 cards for me to wait).

This latter approach works just fine for even huge decks. For example, it takes about 64 ms on this laptop to find out that using a 10,000-card deck, it takes 2^5*3^3*5^2*7^2*11*13*17*19*23*29*41*43*47*53*59*61 = 515,373,532,738,806,568,226,400 rounds to get to the original order. 
(Printing the result with zero decimals using a double-precision floating-point number yields slightly smaller result, 515,373,532,738,806,565,830,656 due to the limited precision.)

It took almost 8 seconds to calculate that a deck with 100,000 cards the number of rounds is 2^7*3^3*5^3*7*11^2*13*17*19*23*31*41*43*61*73*83*101*113*137*139*269*271*277*367*379*541*547*557*569*1087*1091*1097*1103*1109 ≃ 6.5*10^70.

Note that for visualization purposes, I used the following snippet to describe the card position changes during one round:

```
    printf("digraph {\n");
    for (i = 0; i < cards; i++)
        printf("\t\"%lu\" -> \"%lu\";\n", (unsigned long)i + 1UL, (unsigned long)graph[i] + 1UL);
    printf("}\n");
```

Simply feed that output to e.g. `dot` from [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org) to draw a nice directed graph.

Comment: Great answer @Nominal Animal! Could you pls share the complete source code somewhere?? Thank you!

Comment: @Bill: Sure -- although there is not much that is not already shown above. The source for the list-based version is [here](http://nominal-animal.net/answers/stackoverflow-29420602-lists.c), and the source for the array-based version is [here](http://nominal-animal.net/answers/stackoverflow-29420602-arrays.c) (on my own website).

Answer (score 1):

The number of rounds needed to restore the deck to its original state is equal to the least-common-multiple (LCM) of the lengths of the rotation groups<sup>[1]</sup>.

For a simple example, consider a deck of 3 cards labeled `ABC`. Applying the procedure in the question, the deck will go through the following sequence, arriving back at the start position after 3 rounds.

```
ABC     original
BCA     after 1 round
CAB     after 2 rounds
ABC     after 3 rounds the deck is back to the original order
```

Notice that in each round, the first card goes to the end of the deck, and the other two move forward one position. In other words, the deck rotates by 1 position each round, and after three rounds it's back where it started.

For a more interesting example, consider a deck of 11 cards. The state of the deck for the first few rounds is

```
ABCDEFGHIJK
FJBHDKIGECA
KCJGHAEIDBF
ABCIGFDEHJK
```

Notice that during the first round, A moved to the location where K was, K moved where F was, and F moved where A was. So A,F, and K form a rotation group of size 3. If we ignore the other letters and just watch A,F, and K, we see that AFK return to their original positions every three rounds.

Likewise `BCJ` form a group of 3, and `DEGHI` form a group of 5. Since some of the cards return to their original position every 3 rounds, and the others return every 5 rounds, it follows that the deck will return to its original state after `LCM(3,5) = 15` rounds.

<sub>[1] Wikipedia refers to them as [cyclic groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group). Not sure that's of much use to anyone, other than to note that the OP's question falls into a category of mathematics known as [group theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory).</sub>

---

**Computing the LCM**

The least-common-multiple (LCM) of a list of numbers `array[i]` is defined as the smallest number `product` such that each number in the list divides evenly into the product, i.e. `product % array[i] == 0` for all `i`.

To compute the LCM, we start with `product = 1`. Then for each `array[i]` we compute the greatest-common-divisor (GCD) of the `product` and `array[i]`. Then multiply `product` by `array[i]` divided by the GCD.

For example, if the product so far is 24 and the next number is 8, then `gcd(24,8)=8` and we compute `product=product * 8/8`. In other words the product doesn't change because 8 already divides evenly into 24. If the next number is 9, then `gcd(24,9)=3`, so `product=product * 9/3 = 72`. Note that 8,9, and 24 all divide evenly into 72.

This method of computing the LCM eliminates the need for factorization (which in turn eliminates the need to compute the list of primes).

```
int computeLCM( int *array, int count )
{
    int product = 1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        int gcd = computeGCD( product, array[i] );
        product = product * (array[i] / gcd);
    }
    return( product );
}

int computeGCD( int a, int b )
{
    if ( b == 0 )
        return( a );
    else
        return( computeGCD( b, a % b ) );
}
```

Comment: That is really cool!!! Group theory is a really large topic. Will I be able to find these groups without knowing all of it? Is it possible to deduce from the size of the deck how many groups will be there as well as their size?

Comment: @flashburn: it is possible, but at least I would have to use arrays.

Comment: @user3386109: Exactly how would you define this when there are more than two groups? The calculation is not an issue (my answer works); using prime factorization and recording the highest power of each prime factor in any group size works just fine. I'm just having difficulty explaining it in my answer. As an example, a deck of 19 cards has five cycles: one group of 10, one group of 5, one group of 2, and two groups of 1. We know the result is 10 rounds, so `LCM(10,5,2,1) = 10`.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, I basically assumed `LCM(n1,n2,..,nN) = LCM(nN,LCM(nN-1,...LCM(n2,n1)))`, which boils down to the product of the prime factors of those n, with each prime raised to the highest power it was a factor of. Uh. I'm not a math guy, obviously.

Comment: @flashburn The array-based method that NominalAnimal posted is the method that I used to find the group lengths. It may be possible to find a purely mathematical method to calculate the group lengths, but that is not obvious. So I left it as an exercise for the reader ;) My intent was just to start you in the right direction.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Your answer is amazing. It covered pretty much all the code that I wrote. In my code, I tested all deck sizes up to 99, so I can confirm that all of the results that you posted are correct. I've added a section to my answer that shows a slightly different way to compute the LCM. (Note that the recursive definition of LCM in your last comment is also correct, and factorization to find the prime powers is a perfectly valid method for computing the LCM.)

Answer (score 1):

I used linked list for this problem. Create a node structure the standard way as follows:

```
    /*link list node structure*/
    struct Node{                    
        int card_index_number;
        struct Node* next;
    };
```

Defined a function 'number_of_rotations' which takes in an integer as a parameter on function-call (the number of cards in the deck) and returns an integer value, which is the number of rounds taken to obtain the same order of cards in the deck. The function is defined as follows:

```
    int number_of_rotations(int number_of_cards){           // function to calculate the 
        int number_of_steps = 0;
        while((compare_list(top))||(number_of_steps==0)){   // stopping criteria which checks if the order of cards is same as the initial order 
            number_of_steps++;
            shuffle();              // shuffle process which carries out the step 1-2
        }
        return number_of_steps;
    }
```

The while loop used in this function has a stopping criteria of match found for the order of cards in the deck when compared to the original order. This value for the stopping criteria is calculated using the function 'compare_list'. It also makes use of the function 'shuffle' which carries out the steps 1-2; the while loop carries out the step 3. The function used to compare the order of cards is defined below:

```
    int compare_list(struct Node* list_index){// function to compare the order of cards with respect to its original order
        int index = 1;
        while(list_index->next!=NULL){
            if(list_index->card_index_number!=index){
                return 1;
            }
            list_index=list_index->next;
            index++;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The function shuffle is defined as below:

```
    void shuffle(){
        struct Node* table_top= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  //pointer to the card on top of the card stack on the table
        struct Node* table_bottom  = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  //pointer to the card bottom of the card stack on the table
        struct Node* temp1 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  //pointer used to maneuver the cards for step 1-2
        table_bottom=NULL;
        while(1){
            temp1 = top->next;
            if(table_bottom==NULL){  // step 1: take the card from top of the stack in hand and put it on the table
                table_bottom=top;
                table_top=top;
                table_bottom->next=NULL;
            }
            else{
                top->next=table_top;
                table_top=top;
            }
            top=temp1;  // step 2: take the card from top of the stack in hand and put it behind the stack
            if(top==bottom){  // taking the last card in hand and putting on top of stack on the table
                top->next=table_top;
                table_top=top;
                break;
            }
            temp1 = top->next;
            bottom->next=top;
            bottom=top;
            bottom->next=NULL;
            top=temp1;
        }
        top=table_top; //process to take the stack of cards from table back in hand
        bottom=table_bottom;  //process to take the stack of cards from table back in hand
        table_bottom=table_top=temp1=NULL;  // reinitialize the reference pointers
    }
```

This part is additional. These following functions were used to generate the linked list for the cards in the deck and the other function was used to print the indices of the cards in the deck in order.

```
    void create_list(int number_of_cards){
        int card_index = 1;
        //temp and temp1 pointers are used to create the list of the required size 
        struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));      
        while(card_index <= number_of_cards){
            struct Node* temp1 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
            if(top==NULL){
                top=temp1;
                temp1->card_index_number=card_index;
                temp1->next=NULL;
                temp=top;
            }
            else{
                temp->next=temp1;
                temp1->card_index_number=card_index;
                temp1->next=NULL;
                bottom=temp1;
            }
            temp=temp1;
            card_index++;
        }
        //printf("\n");
    }


    void print_string(){                    // function used to print the entire list
        struct Node* temp=NULL;
        temp=top;
        while(1){
            printf("%d ",temp->card_index_number);
            temp=temp->next;
            if(temp==NULL)break;
        }
    }
```

This program has been tested for many input cases and it performs accurately to all the tested cases!

Answer (score 1):

This question (and the answers) are interesting since they reveal how difficult it is to discard the use of an obviously useful tool (in this case, "containers" in the general sense, which includes stacks, arrays, queues, hashmaps, etc.) The interview question (which, as it says, is *not* a trick question) asks for a solution to a problem without using any container. It does not ask for an *efficient* solution, but as we will see, the container-free solution is pretty good (though not optimal).

First, let's consider the computation of the cycle-length for the permutation. The usual computation is to [decompose the permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation) into [orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers) (or "rotation/cycle groups"), and then compute the least-common-multiple (LCM) of the lengths of the orbits. It is not obvious how to do this decomposition without an array but it is easy to see how to compute the cycle length for a single element: we just trace the progress of the single element through successive permutations, counting until we get back to the original location.

```
/* Computes the cycle length of element k in a shuffle of size n) */
static unsigned count(unsigned n, unsigned k) {
  unsigned count = 1, j = permute(n, k);
  while (j != k) {
    j = permute(n, j));
    ++count;
  }
  return count;
}
```

That would be sufficient to solve the problem, because the LCM of a list of numbers is not changed by including the same number more than once, since the LCM of a number and itself is the number itself.

```
/* Compute the cycle length of the permutation for deck size n */
unsigned long long cycle_length(int n) {
  unsigned long long period = count(n, 0);
  for (unsigned i = k; k < n; ++k) {
    period = lcm(period, count(n, k));
  }
  return period;
}
```

But we can do better than that: Suppose we only count cycles which *start with their smallest element*. Since every orbit has a unique smallest element, that will find every orbit exactly once. And the modification to the above code is very simple:

```
/* Computes the cycle length of element k in a shuffle of size n)
   or returns 0 if element k is not the smallest element in the
   cycle
*/
static unsigned count(unsigned n, unsigned k) {
  unsigned count = 1, j = permute(n, k);
  while (j > k) {
    j = permute(n, j));
    ++count;
  }
  return j == k ? count : 0;
}
/* Compute the cycle length of the permutation for deck size n */
unsigned long long cycle_length(int n) {
  /* Element 0 must be the smallest in its cycle, so the following is safe */
  unsigned long long period = count(n, 0);
  for (unsigned k = 1; k < n; ++k) {
    unsigned c = count(n, k);
    if (c) period = lcm(period, c);
  }
  return period;
}
```

Not only does this reduce the number of LCM computations needed, it also reduces the tracing time considerably, because we bail out of the loop as soon as we find a smaller element in the cycle. Experimentation with deck sizes up to 20,000 showed that the number of calls to permute slowly increases with the deck size but the largest average number of calls per element was 14.2, for deck size 14337. The permutation for that deck size is a single orbit, so the naive algorithm would have called `permute` 14337<sup>2</sup> (205,549,569) times, while the above heuristic only does 203,667 calls.

Computing the least-common multiple is straight-forward, by [reducing by the greatest common divisor (GCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Reduction_by_the_greatest_common_divisor), using the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to compute the GCD. There are other algorithms, but this one is simple, fast, and container-free:

```
unsigned long long gcd(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b) {
  while (b) { unsigned long long tmp = b; b = a % b; a = tmp; }
  return a;
}
unsigned long long lcm(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b) {
  unsigned long long g = gcd(a, b);
  return (a / g) * b;
}
```

Cycle length increases rapidly, and even using `unsigned long long` the value soon overflows; with 64-bit values, the first overflow is deck size 1954, whose cycle length is 103,720,950,649,886,529,960, or about 2<sup>66.5</sup>. Since we can't use floating point arithmetic with this form of LCM computation, we'd need to find a multiprecision library to do it, and most such libraries use arrays.

It only remains to write the `permute` function itself. Of course, the temptation is to simulate the deck using some sort of container, but that's really not necessary; we can just trace the progress of an individual card.

If a card is in an even location in the deck (counting the first card as location 0), then it will immediately be put onto the table. Since that happens in order, card 2*k* will be the *k*<sup>th</sup> card placed on the table. (That corresponds to position *n*-1-*k* in the final deck of *n* cards, since the first card placed on the table is the last card in the final deck.)

Cards in odd locations will be put at the (current) end of the deck; in effect, that has the consequence of giving them a new location in a sort of augmented deck. Since every second card is always removed from the deck, the total size of the augmented deck -- that is, the number of cards handled during a round -- is twice the size of the original deck. If the new location is even, the card will be placed on the table and the previous formula still applies; otherwise, yet another location will be applied to the card.

Before attempting to compute the formula for the new locations, here is a useful observation: Suppose some card is at the *odd* location *k*, and the next location will be *k'*. Now suppose that *k'* is also odd, so that the card will then be placed in location *k''*. Now, *k'* − *k* must be even, because both *k* and *k'* are odd. Furthermore, exactly half of the cards between *k* and *k'* will be discarded onto the table before *k'* is reached, and the other half are placed onto the deck following *k'*. Since *k''* must be the next location, we can see that *k''* − *k'* = ½(*k'* - *k*). So once we've computed the offset of the first relocation, it is trivial to compute the remaining offsets; we just divide the offset repeatedly by 2 until we get an odd number, at which point the card is placed on the table.

There is actually a bit-hack to do that computation but since the number of divisions by 2 is small it is simple and more understandable to just do the computation directly. It only remains to compute the first offset, but that's simple: Card 2*k*+1 will be relocated to position *n*+*k*, so the first offset is *n*−*k*−1. So that gives us:

```
/* Find the next position of card k in deck of size n */
/* (The compiler will optimize division by 2 to a shift.) */
unsigned permute(unsigned n, unsigned k) {
  if (k & 1) { /* If k is odd */
    unsigned delta = n - k/2 - 1;
    do { k += delta; delta /= 2; } while (k & 1);
  }
  /* k is now even; k/2 is count from the bottom of the deck */
  return n - 1 - k/2;
}
```

So there's the full program; about 40 lines including comments, and not a container in sight. And the cool part is that it actually runs considerably faster than the solutions which simulate the deck of cards using arrays, linked lists, etc: I was able to generate the non-overflowing cycle lengths of all deck sizes up to 20,000 in 13 seconds, and the 59 orbit lengths for deck size 100,000 in 13 ms. (Granted, I didn't get the LCM, but even so that compares very favourable with 8 seconds, as in one answer which addresses this deck size. I did verify that my computation produced the same result, by computing the LCM in Python from the orbit sizes.)

---

Now, suppose we did have the use of containers. What might be an appropriate use? Clearly, despite all attempts, the above code is calling `permute` many more times than necessary. If we knew which cards were part of an orbit already discovered, we could avoid processing them at all, rather than waiting until the cycle produces a smaller element. Since in the course of computing the orbit, we do compute every element of the orbit, we could just mark each element as "seen" in a bitmap of size `n`. So with a container of `n` bits, we could reduce the number of calls to `permute` to a total of `n`.

Another possible use of an array would be to perform prime factorization of group sizes. For a single cycle-length computation, it is probably simpler to use a bignum package to do the LCM computation, but for repeated computations of different sizes, the LCM computation using prime factorization might well turn out to be superior. This doesn't require a very big array since we only needs primes up to the square root of the maximum deck size. (If a number is not divisible by any prime less than or equal to its square root, then it is a prime.)

---

Note: I know this question was asked quite a while ago; it sprang to my attention because someone added a comment-in-the-form-of-an-answer, raising the question briefly onto the home page where I happened to see it. But it seemed that it hadn't been answered appropriately, and I was bored enough to give the coding exercise a try; hence, this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement "don't use an array" can be fulfilled in various ways. Just because the question is silly for a job interview I would probably go for a double linked list data structure instead.

Now, today I am not in a c-programming mood and there are tons of resources about how to program double linked lists in C... so just for giggles, here a F# implementation which shows what has to be done in the resulting C-program, were it written.

```
type State = { Hand : int list; Table : int list }

let init n = 
    { Hand = [1..n]; Table = List.empty }

let drop state =
    match state.Hand with
    | [] ->  { Hand = state.Table; Table = List.empty }
    | _ -> { Hand = state.Hand.Tail; Table = state.Hand.Head :: state.Table }

let shuffle state = 
    match state.Hand with
    | [] -> { Hand = state.Table; Table = List.empty }
    | _ -> { state with Hand = state.Hand.Tail @ [state.Hand.Head];}

let step state =
    state |> drop |> shuffle

let countSteps n =
    let s0 = init n
    let rec count s c =
        let s1 = step s
        let c1 = if s1.Table = List.empty then c+1 else c
        // printfn "%A" s1
        if s1.Hand = s0.Hand then c1
        else count s1 c1
    count s0 0

[1..20] |> List.iter (fun n -> printfn "%d -> %d" n (countSteps n))
```